# Key up event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one text and one hidden input field.
I want on removing value from input field if it is empty then hidden box value should be zero but this is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('keyup', '#placeByCountryName', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("hi");
         if (($('#placeByCountryName').val().length === 0) || ($('#placeByCountryName').val() === "")) {
             $('#placeByCountryId').val(0);
         }
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="atomAddressDetail.placeByCountryId.id" id="placeByCountryId" value="44" class="addressdetail form-control" />
<input type="text" name="atomAddressDetail.placeByCountryId.name" id="placeByCountryName" class="addressdetail form-control" value="India" placeholder="Country" />
```

But this is not working. 
How to resolve above?

**EDIT** I get some id,name  value from autocomplete to my textbox `placeByCountryName` and its corrosponding id in `placeByCountryId'. If user erase`placeByCountryName`then its`placeByCountryId` should be zero.

Comment: `keyup` will not work on `hidden` inputs. how can you type something inside `hidden` input

Comment: the key is not up from the hidden element,  you must listen the keyup on placeByCountryName input

Comment: How are you trying `keyup` on hidden input? That should be `placeByCountryName` right?

Comment: I get some id,name  value from autocomplete to my textbox `placeByCountryName` and its corrosponding id in `placeByCountryId'. If user erase  `placeByCountryName` then its `placeByCountryId` should be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach event on input type text, not on input type hidden element:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#placeByCountryName', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("hi");
     if (($(this).val().length === 0) || ($(this).val() === "")) {
         $('#placeByCountryId').val(0);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#placeByCountryName', function (e) {
});
```

instead of:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#placeByCountryId', function (e) {
    });
```

Comment: And what about inner if condition??

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `type="text"` as `keyup` will not work on `hidden`

```
<input type="text" id="placeByCountryId" value="44" class="addressdetail form-control" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('keyup', '#placeByCountryId', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("hi");
         if (($(this).val().length === 0) || ($(this).val() === "")) {
             $(this).val(0);
         }
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="atomAddressDetail.placeByCountryId.id" id="placeByCountryId" value="44" class="addressdetail form-control" />
<input type="text" name="atomAddressDetail.placeByCountryId.name" id="placeByCountryName" class="addressdetail form-control" value="India" placeholder="Country" />
```

OR, Bind event on `Country Name` textbox

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#placeByCountryName', function(e) {
    if (($(this).val().length === 0) || ($(this).val() === "")) {
        $('#placeByCountryId').val(0);
    }
});
```